# Adding folders with libs in ant buildfile

Tags: java, ant, jar, classpath, build.xml

in my Project i have the /lib and /WEB-INF folder.
I would need to add both folders (or the .jar files from those folders with sub folders) to the classpath.

I tried something like this, but it didnt work:

```
<property name="lib.dir"        value="lib"/>
<property name="webinf.dir"     value="WEB-INF"/>

<path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
        <include name="${lib.dir}/**/*.jar ${webinf.dir}/**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

Comment: Isn't your WEB-INF folder in 'webContent' folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<property name="web-inf.dir" value="WEB-INF" />
<property name="lib.dir" value="lib" />

<path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${web-inf.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" />
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" />
</path>
```

But shouldn't the web-lib dir be something like `webContent\WEB-INF\lib`?
If yes, then `web-inf.dir` should be:

```
<property name="web-inf.dir" value="webContent/WEB-INF/lib" />
```

Comment: the WEB-INF dir has also a WEB-INF/lib dir which needs to be included